# How to change/add MediaStreamTracks on a running MediaStream?

Tags: javascript, stream, getusermedia, mediastream

I am looking to manipulate a running MediaStream by changing the tracks based on the user selection  i.e., mic selection.

From here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/addTrack it mentions we can add a new track, but from within the MediaStreamTrack api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack there is no Constructor value, as well as most of the properties being "Read Only."  From looking at older posts previously here on StackOverflow I read that there isn't support for adding new tracks and I also read up that the tracks are created when accessing  `getUserMedia()` and starting up the stream.

I did read last night that you can add multiple video/audio streams(but no example), but I'm not sure how that gets set up and how I could loop with the way the code is laid out i.e.,

```
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia 

      ({

         audio: true,
         video:
         {

            width: { min: 1280, ideal: 1920 },
            height: { min: 720, ideal: 1080 }    
         }

      })
```

how would I loop through with the format being like this (or how can I set the format another way besides this) in order to properly setup the devices?  Would it make sense to have multiple video/audio tracks just sticking around?

I was also thinking of redoing each stream, but that seems like a waste of resources and un-needed if I can get another way working.

So my questions are.

1. What ways are available/best-way to change MediaStreamTracks during a running MediaStream?
2. Is it possible to add/remove tracks ourselves?  It seems that the add tracks is internal code, but it's a shame that the methods are available to us, but it seems that we cannot use them.  It seems that removeTracks will work on the tracks in the MediaStream, it just seems that adding is the issue.
3. if we cannot add tracks can I just load up all the tracks and change them as I please, then removing all the ones that aren't needed at the end?

Thank you

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/06/switching-cameras-twilio-video-chat.html
I had to do something like this in Twilio. This article lays out some of the methods they use to do it. Some of it involves their JavaScript SDK, so you may need to decompose some of that to get access to all the methods you need. The things they do with "attach" and "detach" tracks are likely what you need.
Sorry I don't have info on how to do it in Vanilla JS.

Comment: Thanks I ended up figuring out a solution, I appreciate your input.

Comment: @user11116993 what was your solution, care to share?